# How do I calculate quantiles for groups containing infinity?

Tags: quantiles, interpolation

I am looking at prescribing of drug A versus prescribing of drug B. I have the following A/B ratios:

```
None (0/0)
0 (0/100)
0.01 (1/100)
0.05 (5/100)
2.33 (70/30)
Infinity (100/0)
```

How should I calculate the 90th percentile for this group?

UPDATE: These are counts of the number of prescriptions for each drug (prescriptions of A / prescriptions of B). Drug A is considered undesirable, and B desirable.

I want to calculate how many total prescriptions of A could be avoided, if all doctors prescribed at the 10th/20th/50th/75th/90th percentile ratio. Obviously, my real dataset is larger.

Comment: Can you explain these data a bit more?  What is the numerator and what is the denominator?  Are these counts?

Comment: I think the issue of infinite values would only be a problem if you had to interpolate between more than one value to get an estimate of the 90th percentile.  If this is the case one quick fix might be to add a "pseudocount" to both groups so you can never divide by zero.

Comment: @dsaxton so in this example, we have to interpolate, which is why I'm asking the question :) thanks for the suggestion, will see what others think.

Comment: I don't understand the table.  What does $0.1$ have to do with "$1/100$" and what does $0.5$ have to do with "$5/100$"?  And since it has only six lines, what do you mean by their "90th percentile" (which is a quantity that cannot make any sense for such a small set of data)?

Comment: @whuber sorry - typos fixed. I am a software developer writing tests and I want to make sure I have the case covered where a significant proportion (e.g. 150) of the 1000 prescribers don't prescribe drug B at all. Or where the practice at the 89.9th percentile does, but the practice at the 90.1st percentile doesn't. This is how software developers think :) If the answer to that is "the 90th percentile is meaningless in this case" then that's fine, but I wanted to check.

Comment: Your comment suggests you might want to pay attention to the difference between the 90th percentile of some supposed distribution and the *estimated* 90th percentile.  Note that there are many ways to represent ratios without involving infinities. As an example, plot any ratio $y/x$ as a point $(x,y)$ in the plane and record the angle it makes with the horizontal.  The angle (when $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative and at least one is nonzero) will lie between $0$ and $90$ degrees.

Comment: Your question concerns the use of infinity. I have illustrated one of many ways you can compute the percentiles without using infinity.  How you present the data to your users is a completely separate issue: you are free to do that any way you like.

Comment: @whuber I can already rank fine using the existing ratios, the problem is that I need the "real" ratio to calculate how many prescriptions of A could be avoided, in the real world. I'm starting to think the answer is just "round down and don't worry too much" :)

Comment: Your comments, with its reference to a "real" ratio, drugs, and so on, suggest your real question has not been expressed in your post.

Comment: @whuber I'm looking at prescribing of the equivalent drugs rosuvastatin (expensive and therefore undesirable) and atorvastatin (cheaper and therefore desirable) in different prescribers. I've been tasked with workin out how much extra the organisation would save (or spend) if all prescribers prescribed at the 10th percentile, 25th percentile, etc. To do that, I need the real ratio. Not sure that adds much to what's already in the question, but please let me know if anything is unclear...